# Django 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute '_meta' for login by email

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to Allow both email and username login in the Django project, So, I have added additional backends in my `settings.py` file.

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    "accounts.auth.AuthenticationEmailBackend",
    "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",   
)
```

and this is the views file

```
def login_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
            email =request.POST['username']
            password = request.POST['password']
            user = authenticate(username=email, password=password)
            print(user)
            #if user is not None:
            login(request,user,backend="accounts.auth.AuthenticationEmailBackend")
            return redirect('/')
    else:
        pass
    return render(request,'accounts/login.html')
```

and this is the backend

```
class AuthenticationEmailBackend(object):
    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        UserModel = get_user_model()
        try:
            user = UserModel.objects.get(email=username)
        except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
            return None
        else:
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
        return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

when I use my email, I get this error when I click the login button on my form, but when I use my username it works fine and I can log in to my acc

```
'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

Comment: what does object do in this class? what's the purpose to inherit object to class. I think,  you got this error because of this

Comment: I replaced it with ModelBackend but i get the same error again @manoj-tolagekar

Comment: which model you have added? share it here

Comment: `from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend`

Answer (score 0):

Simply you add this in settings.py file:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'appanme.AuthenticationEmailBackend'
```

And check if this solves your error